# Update field in hierarchy data using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, hierarchy

I've a table contains,

```
EmployeeID, ManagerID & EmployeeOrder
```

I need to write `c# code` or `sql statment` to update the `EmployeeOrder` for all records according to the `managerID` relation to be like:

[image: Employee Data]

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to update the EmployeeOrder of one hierarchy and call it recursively:

```
void Update(string ManagerID){
    var employees = DB.Employees.Where(e=>e.ManagerID == ManagerID).ToArray();
    for(int i=0;i<employees.Length;i++){
        employees[i].EmployeeOrder = m.EmployeeOrder + i.ToString("000");
        Update(Employees[i].EmployeeID);
    }
}
```

As with any recursive methods, you have to kick start it. In your case perhaps you would use something like:

```
Update(null);
```

That is, of course, assuming that you're using LINQ to SQL or EntityFramwork or similar so you can use LINQ to access your database. Optionally you can write SQL statement equivalent or Stored Procedure equivalent of the above algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but your solution assume that I have data in "EmployeeOrder" , but in my case I don't have any data in this field I have only EmployeeID & ManagerID & I want to fill this field for all records

Comment: No that is incorrect; if you go through the algorithm it will initialize the first employee with "001".